# Django createsuperuser say key already exist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am confusing about how can I use 'python manage.py createsuperuser' command from the terminal.

When I run this command, it say

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "authtoken_token_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(abcdef@gmail.com) already exists.

But, before use this command, I dropped database and re-create after deleting 000* files in migrations directory.

I checked that there is no line in authtoken_token and user table.
I have no idea what is wrong.

Please give me some advice please.

```
(remoshin) ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-33:~/remoshin/remoshin$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
(remoshin) ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-33:~/remoshin/remoshin$ python3 manage.py  migrate
(remoshin) ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-33:~/remoshin/remoshin$ python3 manage.py dbshell
psql (9.5.8)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

remoshin_maindb=# \dt
                            List of relations
 Schema |                     Name                      | Type  |  Owner
--------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+---------
 public | auth_group                                    | table | remosys
 public | auth_group_permissions                        | table | remosys
 public | auth_permission                               | table | remosys
 public | authtoken_token                               | table | remosys
 public | django_admin_log                              | table | remosys
 public | django_content_type                           | table | remosys
 public | django_migrations                             | table | remosys
 public | django_session                                | table | remosys
 public | remosys_chat_detail_tbl                       | table | remosys
 public | remosys_chat_tbl                              | table | remosys
 public | remosys_clinic_ipaddress_tbl                  | table | remosys
 public | remosys_clinic_open_tbl                       | table | remosys
 public | remosys_clinic_tbl                            | table | remosys
 public | remosys_consultation_menu_tbl                 | table | remosys
 public | remosys_consultation_tbl                      | table | remosys
 public | remosys_department_tbl                        | table | remosys
 public | remosys_error_tbl                             | table | remosys
 public | remosys_menu_tbl                              | table | remosys
 public | remosys_refund_request_tbl                    | table | remosys
 public | remosys_remoshin_doctor_tbl                   | table | remosys
 public | remosys_remoshin_manager_tbl                  | table | remosys
 public | remosys_remoshin_manager_tbl_groups           | table | remosys
 public | remosys_remoshin_manager_tbl_user_permissions | table | remosys
 public | remosys_remoshin_user_tbl                     | table | remosys
 public | remosys_statement_tbl                         | table | remosys
(25 rows)

remoshin_maindb=# select * from authtoken_token;
 key | created | user_id
-----+---------+---------
(0 rows)

remoshin_maindb=# select * from remosys_remoshin_user_tbl;
remoshin_maindb=# select * from authtoken_token_user_id_key";
remoshin_maindb"# select max(id) from authtoken_token_user_id_key;
remoshin_maindb"#
remoshin_maindb=# \q
(remoshin) ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-33:~/remoshin/remoshin$ python3 manage.py createsuperuser

  （omit）

  File "/home/ubuntu/remoshin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "authtoken_token_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(abcdef@gmail.com) already exists.
```